# datetime-local value doesn't appear on input tag

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, input, types

I was making a php page where I can edit a given closing date & time.
After clicking the edit button, the previous value of datetime-local doesn't appear on the datetime box.

Previous value was `2016-06-17 19:07:00`

It only appears like this `mm/dd/yyyy --:--:--`

This one doesn't display the previous value:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="c_datetime" value=<?php echo $row[5] ?> />
```

But when I do it like this it properly display the date and time.

```
<?php echo $row[5] ?>
```

How to make it display the previous value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the date stored in the database? If it is in the wrong format it will not work. If this is the case then you should do `$date = new DateTime($row[5])` then `echo $date->format(d/m/Y H:i);`

Comment: when I created the database: `c_datetime datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `

when storing it
`<input type="datetime-local" name="c_datetime" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be missing some quotation marks around the php code:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="c_datetime" value="<?= str_replace(" ", "T", $row[5]) ?>" />
```

Comment: the other row is working without the parens on value since I enter it on php.. I also tried putting parenthesis but still the same.

Comment: Sorry, I meant quotation marks within your HTML to contain whatever gets echoed by the php code.  As yours currently stands, your HTML will look like this <input type="datetime-local" name="c_datetime" value=2016-06-17 19:07:00 />, but that date stamp needs quotation marks around it.

Comment: I tried to do it this way `<input type="datetime-local" name="c_datetime" value="2016-06-17 19:07:00" />` and still it doesn't appear but when I do it like this `<input type="datetime-local" name="c_datetime" value=2016-06-17T19:07:00 />` it already appeared on the box.

It needs a letter "T" in between the date and time. What I don't know is how am I supposed to put that?

Comment: Looks like you could use str_replace to replace the space with a T... value="<?php echo str_replace(" ", "T", $row[5]) ?>"

Comment: No problem.  It would probably be more technically correct to use the date() function to ensure proper formatting of the output string.  This would be especially true if $row[5] is not guaranteed to be in the format you specified.