# Passing php value to a datetime-local default value

Tags: php, html

I searched the site for this and came up with this [datetime-local value doesn't appear on input tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104837/datetime-local-value-doesnt-appear-on-input-tag) but it's not working for me.

I have the follwoing php code called nowdatetime.php:

```
<?php 
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); 
?>
```

and I'm trying to pass this to an HTML datetime-local value:

```
<input type='datetime-local' name='todate' step='1'  value="/scripts/stats/nowdatetime.php" required/>
```

but nothing happens.  I also changed the datetime-local to a text such as this:

```
<input type='text' name='todate' step='1'  value="/scripts/stats/nowdatetime.php" required/>
```

an all that shows is the script path.

How can I get the value from the php script to e the default for the datetime-local?  I'll try anything.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use jquery check the includes, then try to add a id to your input :

```
<input type='datetime-local' id="todate" name='todate' step='1'  value="/scripts/stats/nowdatetime.php" required/>
```

then you can try an ajax call, to get the content of the result in /scripts/stats/nowdatetime.php file.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#todate").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/scripts/stats/nowdatetime.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {$("#todate").val(data);}
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

then click and see how it changes.

Comment: Although I did what was suggested by @awesomeguy i will test this method as it seems to be another way to get what I want and may use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX also works but you can just include the php in your HTML:

`<input type='text' name='todate' step='1'  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); ?>" required/>`

You just need to make sure that the file your HTML is in is a .php file.

Comment: So what I did was basically renamed the file from html to php and added the php code to the value and it worked.  I now have to clean up the index.php so that it is a proper php code.

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way! Here's how to set a value using php for input field with type="datetime-local"
setting value using php in type="datetime-local"

```
$reg_datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($_POST['submit_from']));
$from_for_val=  date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($reg_datetime));
```

Below is html form input field with type="datetime-local" and its showing how to set value inside input field

```
   <input type="datetime-local" name="submit_from" value="<?=$from_for_val;?>" >
```